# Need help converting verilog to vhdl

Tags: vhdl

please can anyone help me convert the following Verilog to vhdl. Thank you.

```
//Module to inject errors into Hamming Code
 module InjectError(input [7:0] Din,
input [4:0] Pin,
output [7:0] Dout,
output [4:0] Pout,
input [12:0] Ein);
 assign {Dout, Pout} = {Din, Pin} ^ Ein;
 endmodule
```

Comment: There is no indication that you tried at all. A better question would include your attempt at converting to VHDL and questions about why it didn't work (if it didn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of array aggregates is standard version compliance dependent in VHDL, and if you intend synthesis is dependent on version support in your synthesis tools.

Also a VHDL entity and architecture pair corresponds to a Verilog module;

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity InjectError is
    port (
        Din:        in  std_logic_vector  (7 downto 0);
        Dout:       out std_logic_vector  (7 downto 0);
        Pin:        in  std_logic_vector  (4 downto 0);
        Pout:       out std_logic_vector  (4 downto 0);
        Ein:        in  std_logic_vector (12 downto 0)
    );
end entity;
architecture foo of InjectError is
begin
-- always works:
    Dout <= Din xor Ein(12 downto 5);
    Pout <= Pin xor Ein(4 downto 0);
end architecture;
```

In place of the two concurrent signal assignment statements shown in the architecture body using an aggregate signal assignment in IEEE Std 1076-1993 (this always works, too):

```
( Dout(7),Dout(6),Dout(5),Dout(4),Dout(3),Dout(2),Dout(1),Dout(0),
  Pout(4),Pout(3),Pout(2),Pout(1),Pout(0) ) <=
          ( Din(7),Din(6),Din(5),Din(4),Din(3),Din(2),Din(1),Din(0),
          Pin(4),Pin(3),Pin(2),Pin(1),Pin(0) ) xor Ein;
```

wherein the the aggregate element size must match the element size on the right hand side, and this also obeys the rules (and works everywhere):

```
( Dout(7),Dout(6),Dout(5),Dout(4),Dout(3),Dout(2),Dout(1),Dout(0),
  Pout(4),Pout(3),Pout(2),Pout(1),Pout(0) ) <= (Din & Pin) xor Ein;
```

The target of an assignment basic operation must be named so a concatenation on the left hand side of the signal assignment won't work.

IEEE Std 1076-2008 added paragraph 2 in 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates:

> For an element association with a choice that is a discrete range and an expression of the element type of the aggregate, the value of the expression is the element at each index value in the range.

Which allows slices or aggregate elements that have non-matching index ranges (`Dout` and `Pout`, `Din` and `Pin`):

```
(Dout, Pout) <= (Din, Pin) xor Ein;
```

And looks much more Verilog-ish, but again is synthesis tool VHDL version support dependent.

The port type std_logic_vector was selected to take advantage of general mixed language support in simulation and synthesis, where the mapping between std_ulogic and wire is well accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY error_injector IS
    PORT
    (
        d_in    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);    
        p_in    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 DOWNTO 0);
        d_out   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        p_out   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 DOWNTO 0);
        e_in    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END ENTITY error_injector;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF error_injector IS
    SIGNAL tmp      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    tmp <= (d_in & p_in) XOR e_in;
    d_out <= tmp(12 DOWNTO 5);
    p_out <= tmp(4 DOWNTO 0);
END;
```